# How to add several columns to a variable in Visual Basic (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, basic

I have an issue of assigning several columns to a variable in Visual Basic. Is this possible at all?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Do
  Dim data As String
  data = wsh.Cells(Row, 2) 'Data for barcodes is taken from this column
```

Now my question is: how can I assign/store more columns to a data variable? The method i tried below isn't permitted:

```
 data= wsh.Cells(Row,2), wshCells(Row, 3), wshCells(Row, 4)
```

Basically, what I want to do is to take several columns that have some integer values. Out of these values, I want to generate QR Code and populate some specific columns with the generated QR code. With the current method that I have, I can only select one single column and populate another column. I can't select multiple columns and populate multiple columns respectively.

This is one the QR code is inserted into a specific column.

```
Set qrcode_cell = wsh.Cells(Row, 1) 'The cell where the QR Code will be placed
```

*Note i am using an excel add on tool called StrokeScribe.

Your help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply use an array ?

Comment: You have declared data as a String. String is a single piece of text. If you want to append each string next to eachother you can use data = wsh.Cells(Row,2) & wshCells(Row, 3) [but I doubt this is what you want]. Instead you will want to declare data as a Range, which is basically a group of cells. Or, you could declare data as an Array, which is like manually creating a grid with x dimensions, to manually create your own table of data. Do you have experience with either?

Answer (score 0):

Transform your data variable into a list

```
dim datas() as string, pos as integer
pos = -1

' Add a column to datas
public sub addColumn(byval row as integer, byval col as integer)
    pos = pos + 1
    redim preserve datas(pos)
    datas(pos) = wsh.Cells(row, col)
end sub

' Convert your datas into the format of your qrcode
public function retrieveData() as string
   retrieveData = ""
   dim data as string
   for each data in datas
      ' data is the string you had in wsh.Cells(Row, col)
      ' do what you want with this column
   next

   ' affect the result to "retrieveData" to retrieve datas in the needed format
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append each cell value to the existing string using `&`:

```
Do
  Dim data As String
  data = wsh.Cells(Row,2) & wsh.Cells(Row, 3) & wsh.Cells(Row, 4)
```

If you mean you want to add a value each time you loop then something like:

```
Do
  Dim data As String
  data = data & wsh.Cells(Row,2), wshCells(Row, 3), wshCells(Row, 4)
```

So you're just appending the cells onto the existing string.